# Where is the At field for custom shaped bones

Tags: rigging, armature

In Blender 2.79 used to be an At field for placing custom shaped bones at different bones. In the manual of 2.83 there is still a reference to it - see below copied text of the manual

Workflow
To assign a custom shape to a bone, you have to:
Switch to Pose Mode Ctrl-Tab.
Select the relevant bone by clicking on it.
Go to the Display panel Custom Shape field and select the 3D object previously created in the scene; in this example we are using a cube and a cone. You can optionally set the **At field** to another bone.

However, in my version (2.83.1) there is none. Was it moved to a different place or is there a different way to place a custom shaped bone at a different bone?

Comment: I've never seen that field. But I can tell you that I've had a lot of trouble with getting custom bone shapes to work right in the past. Aligning them with the bone when the bone is already in its pose position (as opposed to being newly created, and as such, still at the world space origin) is a pain, and not at all straightforward. I eventually learned that I needed to make sure that the custom bone shape and the bone itself share the same local axis orientation. If they don't, they won't ever align properly.

Comment: "AT" inside bones is now called "Override transform" and it's below the "Custom Object" ( Bone Properties >Bone Shape >)